# Getting Error when Trying to Drop Database

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, beeline

I am stuck with an issue.
I created a External hive table with a wrong HDFS path and then I populated the Data in HDFS Now I am trying to Drop the table and Getting below error

```
18/02/15 08:35:02 [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-54]: ]: ERROR exec.DDLTask: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://abc:8020/usr/log, expected: hdfs://abc3/usr/log         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.dropTable(Hive.java:1084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.dropTable(Hive.java:1015)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.dropTable(DDLTask.java:4013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.dropTableOrPartitions(DDLTask.java:3869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1151)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:197)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$300(SQLOperation.java:76)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$2$1.run(SQLOperation.java:253)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$2.run(SQLOperation.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: MetaException(message:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS
```

Can any one suggest how can we drop the table?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need to update the metadata for the HDFS path you created.

Run this from the Hive Metastore machine.

For example:

/usr/hdp/current/hive/bin/metatool -updateLocation hdfs://nameserviceID/external hdfs://namenode.fqdn:8020/external

To verify, run:

/usr/hdp/version-number/hive/bin/metatool -listFSRoot

Ensure your new paths are listed.

There are some other solutions here:
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: , expected: hdfs://localhost:9000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779976/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-wrong-fs-expected-hdfs-localhost9000)